# Karate DSL - Need to Pass Current Date and Past Date as Parameters in the Get request

Tags: karate

https://stackoverflow/v1/questions?**time_from=2021-03-08T17:15:26&time_to=2021-03-08T17:21:26**

need to pass from date&time and to in parameters

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'path' keyword and supply as many url parameters as you like, see the guide from below link.
https://github.com/intuit/karate#path

Also you can dynamically generate date time string using javainterop function. See below link.
https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-interop